# Why is my string still empty?

Tags: perl

I'm wondering why my string is still empty when just hitting enter after this code:

```
$file = <>;
if ($file eq "") {
$file = "test.txt";
}
print "$file";
```

If I type in anything, it is presented by the print command, but when I just hit enter, nothing is printed out. What I want is for perl to understand when the user inputs nothing and automatically edit the string to, in this case, test.txt. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for so long now :P I never even thought about hitting enter as \n, just thought of it as ignoring the request for an input. As you probably figured, I'm new to Perl. I used $file =~ /^\s*$/ and it works just the way I want. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and happy coding! Remember to accept the answer (green check mark) if this helped you -- it gets me more Meaningless Internet Points :)

Comment: If you have another question, open up a new question for it -- this isn't the right way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because "enter" is not equal to nothing -- it's equal to `\n`.

```
$file = <>;
if ($file eq "") {
$file = "test.txt";
}
print length($file);
```

Run this, hit `ENTER`, and watch as you get -- 1!

Try:

```
$file = <>;
if ($file eq "\n") {
$file = "test.txt";
}
print "$file";
```

Bear in mind that `\n` isn't portable across systems. What you *really* want is something like:

```
$file = <>;
if ($file =~ /^\s*$/) {
$file = "test.txt";
}
print $file;
```

to match on whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

To get the result you want you have to **chomp** your line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $file = <>); #remove newline. $file will have empty string if only a newline was entered.
if ($file eq "") {
$file = "test.txt";
}
print "$file\n";
```